# i18n-js "missing translation" in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app that has the languages English, French, and German. I have some JavaScript code that I need to translate. I used the i18n-js gem, but it doesn't work.

My setup:

Manifest.js:

```
//= require i18n
//= require i18n.js
//= require i18n/translations
```

config/application.rb:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = :de
```

I only want the German version right now, so this is correct.

config/i18n-js.yml:

```
 translations:
   - file: "app/assets/javascripts/i18n/translations.js"
     only: "*"
     pretty_print: true
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'i18n-js'
```

Package.json:

```
 "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
```

application.js:

```
import I18n from 'i18n-js'

window.I18n = I18n
I18n.defaultLocale = "de";
I18n.locale = "de";
```

My translations.js file looks like this:

```
I18n.translations || (I18n.translations = {});
I18n.translations["de"] = I18n.extend((I18n.translations["de"] || {}), {
  "activerecord": {
    "attributes": {
      "booking": {
        "comments": "Bemerkungen",
etc.
```

I can access the I18n object in the console, but as soon as I try to display a translation, it doesn't work:
[image: translation missing]

Running `rake tmp:clear` and/or adding `config.middleware.use I18n::JS::Middleware` to my application.rb doesn't work.

Why isnt't it working?